# 14.04 Download Version

Tags: 14.04, downloads

I want to download a 64 bit Ubuntu version for a Toshiba, not a Mac.  When I download what the download site says is a 64 bit version (NOT the MAC version), its properties still read as 64 bit AMD.  What do I do to get the right version?

Comment: yep, you're downloading a correct version.

Answer (score 2):

`x86-64 (also known as x64, x86_64 and AMD64) is the 64-bit version of the x86 instruction set.` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

It's labelled as AMD because AMD designed first X86-64 cpu. It doesn't matter if your cpu is AMD or Intel it's all X86-64. You are downloading the correct iso.

Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop X86-64: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading a correct version of Ubuntu 14.04. It'll work fine for Toshiba x64 machine.

Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop X86-64: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso